# Using font-awesome in React JS

Tags: reactjs, npm, font-awesome

I'm new to React JS and I'm trying to add font-awesome into my project. I have installed Node.js and npm. I have also included the following packages:

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Now, what should I do in index.js to be able to access all fonts and icons from these packages? I have checked multiple sources and information differs from site to site. Could you please explain how it's done and what should be written after "import" at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can import all free font awesome icons with fas and fab prefixes in this way.

At first you need to install these packages.

```
npm i -S @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

And then add fas and fab prefixes from FA lib to your root file

```
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fas } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { fab } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

library.add(fas, fab);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <!-- Icon of fas prefix -->
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="home" />
      <!-- Icon of fab prefix -->
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'google']} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First, make sure your `package.json` has font-awesome. If it does
   not use `npm i font-awesome` to [install it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome).
2. Second, You need to import the `fonts` that are in `css` folder of
   font-awesome. Add the line to your index.js file.
    `import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";`

Answer (score 0):

That information is inside the docs, here is the extract for imports

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />

ReactDOM.render(element, document.body)
```

https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#explicit-import

Comment: Let me give you my honest opinion. You want to include it in your react code, no problem. But I really think you should use the CDN for fontawesome. It will help decrease your bundle size when you deploy your app.

Comment: In addition to that, you also need plugin in webpack to bundle them along. That will add  to your pain.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! Since I'm just staring React JS, the concept of packages and npm is something new to me. That's why I asked this question just to see how it works so in the future I know all options of usage that are out there :)

Answer (score 0):

Just stop the node application, install `babel-loader` finally run `npm start`. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Great Source to the point.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-font-awesome-5-with-react

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

// get our fontawesome imports
import { faHome } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

// create our App
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />
  </div>
);

// render to #root
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```